# Reorder the list using up and down buttons using hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, react-hooks, state

I would like to reorder the list using up and down buttons using hooks. I am not able to do it with a dynamic list. I have attached a screenshot of what I want to do.[From the add field you can add more fields. I want to reorder them using up-down buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eerY.png)
I am new to React so please suggest corrections if anything else is wrong thanks in advance!
Here is the link of the file on github.
https://github.com/Harsh71019/contactForm/blob/master/contactForm.jsx

Comment: Perhaps you can add index in your list by changing it to an array of objects and show that list sort by index.
on the button of move-up and move down just change the index and react will dynamically show the changes.

Comment: you can use npm package for ordering a list I can suggest one package for that, please refer this link for more info about that package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-sortablejs